# How to send keystroke with PcWedge?

Tags: serial-port, keystroke

I am using PcWedge to capture data from a scale through rs232 and send them to my program. I want when the weight is send from my scale to insert it to a certain field when <kbd>F6</kbd> is pressed. I am trying `{F6}` in field `PreKeystrokes`, but nothing happens.

[image: PCWEDGE]
<sub>(source: [softpedia-static.com](http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/PcWedge_1.png))</sub>

The .ini output is the following:

```
[PcWedge]
SerialPort=\\.\COM3
BaudRate=9600
Parity=None
DataBits=8
StopBits=1
FlowControl=XON/XOFF
RDxBuffer=4096
SleepTime=0
Operation=65
PreAmble={F6}
TargetType=0
TargetParam=
PostAmble=
```

What should I fill this box? I am using windows 10

Comment: What framework are you using? Winforms, WPF, ?

Comment: I am using niceform with vbscript to create my aplication... PcWedge could be used in any program like excel from example.. It is a keyboard emulator that redirects data from com port.

Comment: I want F6 to be sent from inside PcWedge prior to weight value in order from my application to catch F6 and do the following: Focus to the right field, empty the value, write the new weight...

Comment: Looks like PCWedge is more of an application. I think you would be better off contacting the author to find out what needs to be done. The documentation does not look like it is available on the site.

Comment: FYI: On Windows 10 both application should be started with identical privileges. If you start PCWedge as administrator, then your application should be started with administrator privileges too. Otherwise the program can't send keystrokes to other application.

Comment: Actually I found that it uses values from this table [link](http://www.k68.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Key_Codes.htm) I do not know how to send "F6" though...